# Desktop Notification using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, notifications

I have a desktop notification about the time out session to notice user when the page is hidden / minimized.

Is it possible that user click on the desktop notification and it will bring the minimized / hidden page to the front?

I have try the click event handle of notification, it is nothing happened / no function on my site.

If it is not possible, can i disable the click function of desktop notification? Because if I click on this notification, it will show a new webpage not the current webpage to me.

[image: Disable the clickable of notification]